# How to build an Angular project on Plunker (include the third party libraries)

Tags: angular, plunker

I encountered a trouble with `angular`, so I want to build a simple Angular project on `Plunker` to ask for help.

I only create a new Plunk, but I don't know how to **include the third party libraries** to this Plunk, for example, `angular2-notification`.

[Angular + Typescript Demo Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/DTDPIRX6BVemTxZs1GhY)

Comment: Go for stackblitz easy like VScode and also more features will get added like forking from git my stack blitz app [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-nested-reactive-form)

Comment: @RahulSingh It's wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: @RahulSingh Though it works well, it always prompts 'Cannot find module 'angular2-notifications'. Why?

Comment: you need to provide proper imports

Comment: @RahulSingh You can see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notification-test?file=app%2Ffirst%2Ffirst.component.ts).

Comment: it works for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154309/discussion-between-niaomingjian-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: Now new option is there for angular guys https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing about Plunker is you can fork other peoples plunks easily to use as the basis for your own. The Angular Material 2 team keep a [demo plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/uuQols?p=preview) up to date which is good to use as a starting point.

Add any third party libraries to config.js and then follow the package instructions as normal.

```
    map: {
        'angular2-notifications': 'npm:angular2-notifications'
    }
```

If it is not available on NPM you can also use [rawgit](https://rawgit.com/) to import directly from a GitHub repo.

Here is [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/uuQols?p=preview) with angular2-notifications added.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Chg3VAAAWulT2IOjtBP5?p=preview).  Mainly you should add library "umd" package in config file.

```
    'ngx-loading': 'npm:ngx-loading/bundles/ngx-loading.umd.min.js'
    'angular2-notifications': 'npm:angular2-notifications/bundles/angular2-notifications.umd.min.js'
```